Why is new Date() giving wrong date for other time zone users?
I have a hotel booking website. When users who are residing in India and have IST time zone try to book a hotel then the date they're seeing is correct. But when users who are outside IST time zone (for example US Eastern Daylight time zone) they're not able see correct date when they select it from calendar.
I have set my laptop to EST time zone. When I select 7th of September 2024 from calendar, I can see props.checkin also has the same date. But when it is passed to new Date(props.checkin) then the date automatically changes to 6th of September 2024. This only happens in a time zone other than IST.
 useEffect(() => {
    console.log(
      "props.checkin>>>>>",
      new Date("Sat Sep 07 2024 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)"),
    );
    dispatch(
      updateBookingDateRange({
        checkInDate: new Date(props.checkin),
        checkOutDate: new Date(props.checkout),
        searchedRoomCount: Number(props.num_rooms),
        searchAdultCount: Number(props.num_adults),
        searchedChildrenCount: Number(props.num_children),
        searchGuestCount: Number(props.num_guests),
      }),
    );

    if (
      totalRoomCount === 0 &&
      props.planStatus &&
      router.query.roomId &&
      router.query.planId
    ) {
      dispatch(
        addFirstRoom({
          roomInfo: props.roomDetails,
          planInfo: props.planDetails,
          roomCount: props.num_rooms,
          guestCount: Number(props.num_guests),
          adultCount: Number(props.num_adults),
          childCount: Number(props.num_children),
        }),
      );
    }
  }, [
    router.query.hotelInfo,
    router.query.checkin,
    router.query.checkout,
    router.query.num_guests,
    router.query.num_children,
    router.query.num_rooms,
  ]);

I expect that when users who are in a different time zone choose some date then they too should see the correct date instead of the wrong date.

You haven't shown how you are actually using that Date object, but it's likely you're displaying the timestamp to your users in their respective timezone.

I wouldn't use a JavaScript Date for this. I would use a date string ('YYYY-MM-DD', e.g. '2024-09-07') or a date number (YYYYMMDD, e.g. 20240907) for this use case. A JavaScript Date doesn't have any advantages and makes it unnecessarily complex. Many date picker libraries allow this.

When new Date(props.checkin) is called, JavaScript interprets this date in your local time zone (in your case, EST), which can cause the date to shift, especially if the time part is set to midnight in IST.
If you're in EST (which is UTC-4 or UTC-5 depending on daylight saving), it might adjust to the previous day due to the time difference.
You can handle this by normalizing the date to avoid time zone issues. One common approach is to use the ISO format without specifying the time part (or explicitly setting the time to midnight in the user's time zone) or use libraries like date-fns or moment-timezone to manage time zones effectively.
I personally recommend to use date-fns to manage timezones perfectly as i faced the same problem which solved by using date-fns.

Re "…JavaScript interprets [props.checkin] in your local time zone". Not necessarily. The timestamp used in the OP conforms to the format of Date.prototype.toString and includes an offset. So the supplied offset is factored into the generated time value. All conforming implementations must generate the same time value regardless of system settings. If the format coming from the calendar is YYYY-MM-DD, then it will be parsed as UTC, so again not affected by host settings.
